# PowerPoint file --> 'missing font' error when opened in Keynote

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint, iwork-keynote

Here is our situation.

We have a nice PowerPoint Office 2007 presentation file (`.pps`) which opens on all devices -- Windows, Mac, desktops, tablets, iPhones.

Only when opened in Keynote on a Mac the following error message appears:

[image]

Please note:

- the .pps file has 23 slides
- all the slides are (screenshot) PICTURES ONLY, there is no written text in the PowerPoint presentation (at least we didn't write anything, and nothing's visible either)
- the file can be opened after this message, but it is annoying for the recipient and we really want to find a way to save the .pps file without triggering this
- saving as pdf is not an option, it must be the ppt/pps file
- we know that the standard font in PowerPoint is Calibri, and Macs don't have this font installed, so we went to the Slide Master, and whatever we could find there that was set to Calibri, we switched to Arial. After we did that, though, we even got more "MasterSlide" error messages, see our screenshot above.

Again, the file does open, but we need to figure out what we can do to avoid this unprofessionally-looking error message our Mac user recipients encounter.

Comment: Have you tried [embedding the "missing" font](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/826832)?

Comment: Font embedding doesn't work on Mac Office, so wouldn't help.

Comment: When you say you went to the Slide Master, do you mean just the master slide at the top of the list, or did you visit EACH master (if more than one) and each layout under each of the masters?  Have you tried using PowerPoint's Replace Fonts feature to convert Calibri to Arial?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Steve! "When you say you went to the Slide Master, do you mean just the master slide at the top of the list, or did you visit EACH master (if more than one) and each layout under each of the masters?" --> we did each master. But this didn't help. The amount of error pages just multiplied as seen in the screenshot above. "Have you tried using PowerPoint's Replace Fonts feature to convert Calibri to Arial?" --> sounds good. How to do that in PowerPoint 2007?

Comment: You probably really should register an account, then use the contact us link to merge things. Unregistered accounts do wierd stuff like this.

Comment: I don't have 2007 handy but it should be fairly similar to 2010, where you'd do:  Home tab | Editing group | Replace, but instead of clicking Replace itself, click the downward pointing triangle next to it; that gives you a dropdown that includes a Replace Fonts option.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late coming back to this party, but I may've just had an AHA moment.

Keynote is barking at the Office Theme, which is the standard theme that your presentation's built on, most likely.

Themes can include font information among other things ... the font theme controls which fonts are used by default for headings and other text.  You may have used entirely different fonts for all of your text, but Keynote may be assuming that Theme Font = Used Font.  And complaining about it.

Try creating a new font theme that uses heading and body fonts that are installed on all of your target platforms (whatever you're using now, for example, since those seem to be working out well).  Apply the new font theme then try opening in Keynote.